# Build Notion like filter options as part of a configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript

To goal is to build a system that can configure some constraints. Similar to what Notion does with their filter properties.

[image]

System A configures the constraints and system C evaluates the constraints. Both use Typescript. However, the constraints are stored in a Rust environment (system B). This system should be modified as little as possible. So the data flow is:

System A (TS) -> System B (Rust) -> System C (TS)

System A and C know the the data structures but only system C knows about the actual values that are being evaluated. Thus, system A must define these constraints in an abstract way.

**My best solution right now**:

1. store these constraints as JS expressions in the form of strings. For example system A produces the following constraint:

```js
const expression = "'${NAME}' === 'Zurich'"
```

2. System B can easily store this constraint without any necessary conversion since it is just a string.
3. System C takes the input that it received from the user and replaces it with the placeholder `${NAME}` and can call the JS function `eval()` which can evaluate strings as JS code.

**Questions**:

- What is the name of this problem so I can google it better? :) Is this sort of a query language?
- Do you see a problem with the approach of storing strings and calling `eval()` on them?
- Or any better ideas to achieve this?
- Any libraries known that can help me with writing more complex constraints?

**Background**:
The real use case might help understand the problem better:
The system that is being built is a decentralized voting system.

- System A is the voting authority and configures a ballat and who is allowed to vote.
- This configuration is stored in a public ledger (System B)
- System C is responsible to generate access tokens to eligible votes. A voter must reveal some proof. For example a passport signed by one of the eligible states (constraints). These constraints are read directly from the ballot configuration from the blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a little late for your needs, but for future searches, I think what you're looking for is curried functions. Someone answered a similar question over here much better than I could do here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38719906/5656259